# Is the formula λ = h/mc wrong?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

When we derive De Broglie's equation, we can do that from two ways. That's,
**1st step:-**
$E^2=p^2c^2+m_0^2c^4$ 
For a Photon $m_0=0$,
 So, we have ,
$E^2= p^2c^2$,i.e. 
$E=pc$ -----(1)
$E=hc/λ$----(2)
 equating 1) with 2),
$pc=hc/λ$
or,
$p=h/λ$
or,
$λ=h/p \Rightarrow  \textbf{λ=h/mc}$

**2nd step:-**
$E=mc^2$----(1)
$E=hc/λ$----(2)
equating 1 with 2,
$mc^2 = hc/λ$
or,$λ=hc/mc^2 \Rightarrow \textbf{λ=h/mc}$

According to those ways, what's the really correct way to derive that? Is 2nd step wrong?

Comment: Could you please reformat your question so that the equations are more clear. If you need help with the syntax, check: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?lq=1

Comment: For a photon, v=c, which makes both equations identical. Besides, for a photon, m=0, which also makes them both meaningless.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin, **for a photon , $m$(moving mass) is not equal to $0$. It is the rest mass, $m_0$ =$0$. So, we have $m= \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1- \frac{v^2}{c^2}}} $. So, as $v=c$, both the numerator and denominator tends to $o$. You can't just tell that this ratio also tends to $0$, because you have to take limits to tell that.

Comment: What makes you do the step E = m c^2 ? You open your question with the right formula. ...

Answer (score 1):

If you define mass as the mass associated with the total energy of the photon, then Step 2 is correct.  Still (imho), Step 1 is superior because it is not encumbered by having to distinguish between "mass" of the object in motion and "rest mass".

Comment: Sorry, the answer of step 1 should be λ=h/mv. According to that answer what's really correct answer?